# Java string "hello" has 12 bytes when getBytes("UTF-16")?

Tags: java, string, decode, encode

I expected that, when a java character is stored as "UTF-16", each character uses 2 bytes, so "hello" should consume 10 bytes, but this code:

```
String h = "hello";
System.out.println(new String(h.getBytes("UTF-16"), "UTF-16").length());
System.out.println(new String(h.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8").getBytes("UTF-16").length);
```

Will print "5 12"

My question:

(1) I expected that the first println should get "10" as I mentioned. But why 5?

(2) For the second println, I am trying to getBytes for it first as "UTF-8" then as "UTF-16". I suppose it should also be 10. But actually it's 12.

I'm using MAC and my region is HongKong. Would you help to explain what's happening in the program, and how "5 12" actually came out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (1) I expected that the first println should get "10" as I mentioned. But why 5?

You take a 5 character string, encode it as bytes using UTF-16 encoding.
Then you create a new string by decoding the bytes (correctly) from UTF-16, which gives you a new string consisting of your original 5 characters again.

> (2) For the second println, I am trying to getBytes for it first as "UTF-8" then as "UTF-16". I suppose it should also be 10. But actually it's 12.

This part of the code:

```
    new String(h.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")
```

is actually a no-op.  It is just a rather expensive way to copy a string.  You encode the string to bytes using UTF-8 as the encoding scheme, and then you create a new string by decoding the UTF-8 encoded bytes.

So effectively, you are doing this:

```
    "hello".getBytes("UTF-16").length
```

The reason for the extra 2 bytes is that UTF-16 encoding puts a BOM (byte order mark) as the first (2 byte) code unit.

For more information, read the Unicode FAQs on ["UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM"](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

Answer (score 3):

> I expected that the first println should get "10" as I mentioned. But why 5?

You are calling `length()` on the `String`, not on the `byte[]`. So this will give you the length of the String in *characters* (at least as long as we are staying in the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane -- this unfortunately breaks down when you have characters that need variable-length encoding even in UTF-16).

Once you have a String, it does not matter what encoding was used to create it. `length` is always given in terms of characters.

If you converted this into a `byte[]` using UTF-16, you might rightfully have expected 10 (for the five characters times two bytes each) -- that it actually ends up being 12 is due to a Byte Order Mark being included.